# How can one determine if a field is numeric or a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, numbers

I've tried both `CEIL` and `CAST` methods suggested elsewhere. Neither of them work.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CEIL('foo') = 'foo'             THEN 'Str' ELSE 'Num' END AS ceil_test_1,
    CASE WHEN CEIL(123) = 123                 THEN 'Str' ELSE 'Num' END AS ceil_test_2,
    CASE WHEN CEIL('123') = 123               THEN 'Str' ELSE 'Num' END AS ceil_test_3,
    CASE WHEN CAST('bar' AS UNSIGNED) = 'bar' THEN 'Str' ELSE 'Num' END AS cast_test_1,
    CASE WHEN CAST(123 AS UNSIGNED) = 123     THEN 'Str' ELSE 'Num' END AS cast_test_2,
    CASE WHEN CAST('123' AS UNSIGNED) = 123   THEN 'Str' ELSE 'Num' END AS cast_test_3
;
```

Expected Results are obvious: `foo` is a string. `123` is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP` for that purpose.

```
SET @str := 'asdf', @str2 := '1d25';
```

## is SpaceAndAlpha

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN @str REGEXP '^[A-Z a-z]+$' THEN
    'YES'
ELSE
    'NO'
END AS isString; ---twisted from the definition of string;
```

---

## is Nuemric

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN @str2 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN  ---or WHEN TRIM(@str2 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
    'YES'
ELSE
    'NO'
END AS isNumber;
```

**Note:** (In regex, `^` means begin, and `$` means end)

## EDIT:

Another interesting way to check **is Numeric**:

```
SET @str := '  00000007166';

SELECT
    CASE
WHEN CONCAT('',@str*1) = TRIM( LEADING '0' FROM TRIM(@str)) THEN
    'YES'
ELSE
    'NO'
END AS isNumber;
```

**Note1.1:**

First `Trim` function trims the leading and trailing spaces.

Second `trim` function takes into account the leading zeros (if any).

Comment: This is great. But `'^[A-Za-z]+$'` fails with `foo bar`.

Comment: Just allowed space in the `REGEXP`. Please check now.

Comment: So `"String!"` isn't a string? How about `"12 Monkeys"`?

Comment: Thanks @tadman. Btw, my mind's set that the PO asks for `isAlpha() and isNumeric()` function. Everything is string, isn't it? Unless there's no character. Please give me your opinion so that I can improve the answer.

Comment: I'd presume something that isn't all numeric and isn't blank would qualify as a string by default. It seems odd to exclude strings that don't meet some arbitrary definition of being alpha only. This is such a narrow definition that "" would be of unknown type, when I think it would be a string.

Comment: Then can I conclude `IF(CHAR_LENGTH(input) > 0, 'string','not string);` **OR** `IF(LENGTH(input) > 0, 'string','not string)`. @tadman. If yes then which one? else looking forward to getting your suggestion.

Comment: @tadman I agree. How would you recommend changing the above to fit your edge cases?

Comment: The TRIM version should take into account potential leading zeros as well.

Comment: @Ryan I think in the spirit of the original question your numeric detector is sufficient, and if it's not numeric or empty, it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a regular expression to solve a problem, you usually end up with two problems.

Use the information_schema views to determine the data type of a column.

```
create table test (
  test_int integer not null
);

select data_type from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'sandbox'
  and table_name = 'test'
  and column_name = 'test_int';
```

```
data_type
--
int
```